# Kafka stream app shut down when a processor throws an exception uncaught?

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

As topic described,how can i just commit this offset,and continue to process without shutting down the stream app?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the "log and continue" exception handler?

Comment: It doesn't work! This kind of handler for ser and deser,not for exceptions threw by processor

Comment: What exception are you getting, then? Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: every exception not handled in processor

Comment: That's somewhat vague, but if you get a bad message, then that'd be handled by the serializer. If you run into a runtime exception within the context of the processor, that'd be handled by a regular try catch. If you end up with with any other uncaught exception (like an npe) yeah, the app with crash whether or not it's a kstreams app

Comment: You could try using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, but I don't think there's a way to get the threads used in the KStream api,

Comment: The `setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` in KafkaStreams set the java uncaught exception handler. This handler only gets triggered when a thread is dead.

In 2.8 there will be a new handler with the option to replace the thread but even that will still retry the record. If you want to ignore records that are throwing an error it is best to do so in the processor not an uncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: can i commit the offset manually?